# JSP SQL SERVER ResultSet always return empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, jsp

I'm doing two queries to a SQL Server database, the first query returns the Result Set with data, but the second query always returns the Result Set empty. If I do the query in the SQL SERVER, it does it well. I have tried to make another query: `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TABLE` and always returns empty.

```
 <%
    String url,ssql;
    int i,j,k;
    int reg[]=new int[256];
    try{
        Class.forName("com.microsofto.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/;databaseName=acsc;user=user;password=1234";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        Statement stc = conn.createStatement();
        ssql="SELECT Nombre,max(Registro) FROM Tabla Group by Nombre order by Nombre";
        ResultSet rsc= stc.executeQuery(ssql);
        i=1;
        while(rsc.next()){
            reg[i]=rsc.getInt(2);
            i++;
        }
        j=0;
        do{
            //ssql="SELECT * FROM Tabla Where     Registro="+String.valueOf(reg[j]);
            ssql="SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Tabla";
            rsc= stc.executeQuery(ssql);
            if(!(rsc.getRow()==0)){
                out.println(rsc.getString(1)+" "+rsc.getString(2)+" "+rsc.getString(3));    
            }else{
                out.println("vacio");
            }
            j++;
        }while(j<i);
    }catch(SQLException se){
        out.println(se.toString()); 
    }
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code.  The only one you need to fix is that you're not using Parameters in your SQL query.  See

```
public static void executeStatement(Connection con) {
    try(PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM Person.Contact WHERE LastName = ?");) {
        pstmt.setString(1, "Smith");
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("LastName") + ", " + rs.getString("FirstName"));
        }
    }
    // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[Using an SQL Statement with Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-an-sql-statement-with-parameters?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response and sorry for not having responded before.
I have tried using prepareStatement, but the ResultSet kept returning empty.
I finally found where I had the problem, if!(Rsc.getRow()==0)) always returned 0, even if the ResulSet had records.
I have removed that part of the program and I have placed while rsc.next() and it works correctly.
What is the second problem that my code has?
Thanks greetings